# Setting bold with text field and parameter with string "&" scratch pdf

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Im trying to set bold in some part of text field that concats with parameter (noCurso) but when this parameter comes with character "&" scratch my pdf print.

This prints style tag bold besides put in bold the text. And works when parameter not come with "&"

See below my text field

"Eu, "+$P{noAluno}.toUpperCase()+", portador(a) da Cédula de Identidade número "+$P{nuRg}+", declaro, sob as penas da lei, que entregarei todos os documentos necessários para a efetivação da matrícula no curso "+$P{noCurso}.toUpperCase()+". "

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an apache commons library method to escape the special characters in the parameter:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml($P{noCurso}).toUpperCase()
```

More on this issue can be found in the [JasperForge iReport Forums](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=64104&topid=64380).

The Apache Commons Lang API can be found [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/index.html). In particular, you will need to download the commons-lang library [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi/download_lang.cgi).

Comment: As a new user on stackoverflow, you may not be aware that when someone answers a question to your liking, you should click the little check mark next to their answer -- this is called "accepting" the answer. It increases both your reputation and the answerers. Once you get a few reputation points, you can also "upvote" the answer by clicking the little up-arrow next to the answer. Thanks!